# Файлы в Турбо Паскале

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте!

Преподаватель в учебном пособии в теме "Файлы" написал небольшую строчку:
"Не закрытые файлы нарушают файловую структуру на диске, что может приводить к серьезным проблемам с настройкой компьютера".
Хочу узнать именно эту подробность: как именно не закрытые файлы нарушают структуру на диске и какие именно проблемы возникнут с настройкой компьютера?

Comment: интересно, что это за пособие, и какой год издания?

Comment: Это видеопособие, или правильнее видеокурс, издан в 2009 году. К этому видеокурсу приложены и текстовые материалы.

Comment: Если сделать 100500 допущений - то это истина )))

Comment: 100500 допущений чего? Где делать эти допущения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При нормальном завершении процесса происходит сброс всех буферов ввода-вывода и закрытие всех файловых дескрипторов. Другое дело, если процесс завершился аварийно. Вот тогда, если что-то осталось в буфере, то пропало. Тут можно предложить не только закрывать файлы при завершении работы с ними, но и сбрасывать буфер перед достаточно длинным и/или потенциально опасным участком кода, в котором не происходит ввод-вывод. Не знаю, как это делается в Паскале, в С/С++ для этого есть функция fflush.

Если вовремя не закрывать файлы, то может еще и другая проблема возникнуть. При достижении определенного порога, открытие новых файлов происходит немного медленнее, что может затормозить работу программы.

В общем, закрытие файлов, дальнейшая работы с которыми не предусмотрена, - это признак хорошего стиля программирования.

**P.S.** При открытии файла в Windows возможна его блокировка. Если такой файл не закрыть корректно, то могут возникнуть проблемы с дальнейшим доступом к нему. В никсах такой проблемы нет.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такое понятие как буферизованный ввод-вывод. При записи данные сначала заносятся в буфер, а при его заполнении переносятся на жесткий диск. При закрытии файла в том числе происходит запись оставшихся в буфере данных. То есть, если не закрыть файл, то данные, отправленные на запись в конце, могут не записаться.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятность этого около 1%. Если оставить незакрытым выходной файл, то есть шанс, что данные выведенные в этот файл не сохранятся(т.е. файл останется пустым). Других особенностей незакрытых файлов не замечал.

Comment: @Vladimir4152 Как Вы смогли оценить вероятность?

Comment: Практика...

Answer (score 1):

На счёт целостности не знаю, но если не закрыть через CloseFile файл, открытый на запись, могут возникнуть с проблемой изменения файла (перемещения, переименования и т.д.) Таже ситуация может возникнуть и не с корректной работой с TFileStream

Answer (score 1):

По моим наблюдениям, если файл будет не закрыт до выхода из программы, то ОС сама сбросит буфер на диск и закроет файл. Проблемы могут возникнуть при сбое питания или нажатии резет, тогда данные в буфере будут потеряны, а файл не будет закрыт. Поэтому желательно всегда закрывать файл, как только работа с ним завершена.

Comment: при работе в IDE (по крайней мере в Borland Pascal точно) нужно было закрывать файлы, чтобы они обновились. Я думаю это связано с тем, что IDE тоже как-то к ним обращается.